# How disable eslint warning for a specific line in a template in a .vue file in VS Code

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, eslint, vetur

I would like to dismiss this error on my vue file

I am trying to add this processor line

```
<!-- eslint-disable-next-line vue/no-use-v-if-with-v-for -->
```

and

```
<!-- eslint-disable-next-line vue/no-confusing-v-for-v-if  -->
```

but neither

[image]

Nor

[image]

dismiss the eslint warning

> [eslint-plugin-vue] [vue/no-use-v-if-with-v-for]
>   The 'value' variable inside 'v-for' directive should be replaced with a computed property that returns filtered array instead. You should not mix 'v-for' with 'v-if'.
>   I'm using the [vetur](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur) extension for VSCode.

I added the precessor line fallowing [this](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/comment-directive.html#rule-details) sample but eslint still warns about the next line.

PS. This solution is not the best one, but I needed it like this due the transition animation.

Comment: Are you using the latest versions of the tools? I read [here](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/no-confusing-v-for-v-if.html) that this rule has been recently introduced as a replacement of the deprecated `vue/no-confusing-v-for-v-if`.

Comment: Why don't you use a computed property to filter your list as the warning suggests? You could also split your directives and put `v-if` in a `template` tag to separate the two.

Comment: Show your `.eslintrc`, please

Answer (score 29, accepted):

See [Vetur's documentation](https://vuejs.github.io/vetur/linting-error.html#error-checking):

> Install **ESLint plugin** for the best linting experience. **Vetur's template linting is only for quick start and does not support rule configuration**.

So, you have to:

1. Install [ESLint plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint)
2. Enable `vue` plugin and disable Vetur's linting (add to VS Code config):

   ```json
   "vetur.validation.template": false,
   "eslint.validate": [
     "javascript",
     "javascriptreact",
     "vue"
   ]
   ```

If you don't have `eslint` and/or [`eslint-plugin-vue`](https://eslint.vuejs.org/) already installed, you should do that:

```
npm i eslint babel-eslint eslint-plugin-vue --save-dev
```

Simple config for ESLint:

```json
{
  "root": true,
  "env": {
    "node": true
  },
  "extends": ["plugin:vue/essential", "eslint:recommended"],
  "rules": {
  },
  "parserOptions": {
    "parser": "babel-eslint"
  }
}
```

You should save it either to `.eslintrc` file or to `package.json` under `eslintConfig` name.

And, it works:

[image]

Comment: I had all this in place already and found that I had not enabled given vscode permission to use my eslint/eslint configuration.

Comment: @MichaelCole Ask your question separately. For OP's case it did work.

Answer (score 21):

If you really want to disable it, try the solution below (it works for me). Since you are specific about the rule it doesn't disable other warnings:

```
<!-- eslint-disable vue/no-v-html -->
<textarea
  type="email"
  name="message"
  required
  aria-required="true"
  v-html="form.inputs.name.placeholder"
/>
<!-- eslint-enable -->
```

Answer (score -5):

Try `{{! template-lint-disable }}`