# VS Code CSS Classes is being printed on multiple lines

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

Whenever i have many CSS classes for an element, my VS Code prints only one of them on each line, is there any way to mitigate this? By, for instance printing 3-4 classes on each line?

```
 <input class="
            shadow
            appearance-none
            border
            rounded
            w-full
            py-2
            px-3
            text-gray-700
            leading-tight
            focus:outline-none
            focus:shadow-outline
            form__input
"/>
```

Comment: Is that how it's displayed on the screen too?

Comment: @LarryBud :))) ofcourse not. It's about the linter. Depends on what linter the OP uses in vscode. There are settings that you can edit for this.

Comment: I use ESLint, I saw that the printWidth can be altered, but i could not find a setting for showing multiple css classes on multiple lines

Comment: Try putting `// prettier-ignore` or `// eslint-disable-next-line` above the code. May need to use `<!-- prettier-ignore -->` for HTML or maybe `{/* prettier-ignore */}` for JSX depending on your situation?

Comment: @RyanWheale  That did not seem to work! The html in question is within a Vue template (in a Nuxt.JS project), so I would say that `<!-- eslint-disable-next-line -->` should work!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54395111/how-disable-eslint-warning-for-a-specific-line-in-a-template-in-a-vue-file-in-v

Comment: Try **`"html.format.wrapAttributes"`** in your settings. Also, ESLint won't format HTML,  but prettier does format it, and it wraps the attributes. You may need to use a plugin for prettier if you don't like them being wrapped, because prettier is an Opinionated formater, it doesn't give you any options to change things.